# How does cycle prevent a generator from throwing a StopIteration exception?

Tags: python, numpy, iterator, generator, cycle

Considering this example:

```
from itertools import cycle

def foo():
    for i in range(3):
        yield i

c = cycle(foo())

next(c)  # -> 0
next(c)  # -> 1
next(c)  # -> 2 [StopIteration should be thrown here normally]
next(c)  # -> 0
...
```

How does `cycle` prevent the generator from exciting via a `StopIteration`? I thought a generator could only be executed once, since the generator only returns its current value and moves on.

Is `cycle` simply re-creating the generator when `StopIteration` is thrown? Could this become a problem (inefficiency) when I iterate over for example large numpy arrays?

Secondary question: is this a "pythonic" way of cycling large data sets with iterators/generators? Or should I transfer the cycling logic directly to the generator itself (like defining indexes and using a while loop with resetting indexes)?

My intention is to cycle through large data sets (mostly numpy array; >100.000 entries) efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does `cycle` prevent the generator from exciting via a `StopIteration`?

It doesn't. The generator reaches its end and exits with a `StopIteration` as normal. `cycle` stores the generator's output, and when `cycle` sees the `StopIteration`, it switches to producing items from its stored history of what the generator produced.

Comment: That sounds like `cycle` is very memory-inefficient if I use it on large data sets? I mean it has to store every single value ever returned by `yield` then?

Comment: @daniel451: It doesn't really have any other options. You might have other options, since you have more context, but `cycle` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

`user2357112` has answered your first quesiton.

As to your second, for a container like a numpy array, we can create an equivalent to cycle that does not need to make an extra copy in memory. Note that this does not work with generators! We have to store a copy somewhere if we're going to use them over and over, or at least have a way to generate them on demand.

```
def cycle(container):
    if iter(container) is container:
        raise TypeError('need a container, not a generator')
    while True:
       yield from container



# this works correctly for a container
for i, char in enumerate(cycle('abc')):
    print(char)
    if i > 10:
        break
```

Suppose we want to read from a file repeatedly without creating a copy of each line in memory.

We can create a 'wrapper class' that implements `__iter__` and then use our new `cycle` method with it.

```
class Reader():
    def __init__(self, path, *args, **kwargs):
        self.path, self.args, self.kwargs = path, args, kwargs
    def __iter__(self):
        with open(self.path, *self.args, **self.kwargs) as file:
            yield from file

 #eg:
 for line in cycle(Reader(filepath)):
     #somecode
```

Comment: As a final note, you can always use an additional while or for loop instead of `cycle`, calling list() or tuple() first if it is a generator. This is less 'clean' but may be more clear to your intended audience, depending on their familiarity with python and itertool-style idioms.